# How to fetch & store over 100k records to DB from another DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have school database who having more then 80 000 records and I want to update and insert into my newSchool database using php, whenever I try to run query update or insert almost 2 000 records and after some time its stopped automatically please help

Comment: use direct commands to fetch data from server and paste it on your localmachine. take a backup file like backup.sql from your server and import it on another database

Comment: How does it "stop"? Any log entry? Error?

Comment: Don't use PHP or any language to move that volume of data; use `mysqldump` as Michael has explained.  PHP will run out of memory long before the process can complete, where as mysqldump is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could (should) do a full dump and import that dump later. I'm not sure how to do it with php - and think you'd be better doing this with those commands on the cli:

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p -A -R -E --triggers --single-transaction > backup.sql
```

And on your localhost:

```
mysql -u <username> -p < backup.sql
```

The backup statement flags meanings [from the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html):

```
-u
```

> DB_USERNAME

```
-p
```

> DB_PASSWORD
>
> Don't paste your password here, but enter it after mysql asks for it. Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

```
-A
```

> Dump all tables in all databases. This is the same as using the --databases option and naming all the databases on the command line.

```
-E
```

> Include Event Scheduler events for the dumped databases in the output.
>   This option requires the EVENT privileges for those databases.
>
> The output generated by using --events contains CREATE EVENT
>   statements to create the events. However, these statements do not
>   include attributes such as the event creation and modification
>   timestamps, so when the events are reloaded, they are created with
>   timestamps equal to the reload time.
>
> If you require events to be created with their original timestamp
>   attributes, do not use --events. Instead, dump and reload the contents
>   of the mysql.event table directly, using a MySQL account that has
>   appropriate privileges for the mysql database.

```
-R
```

> Include stored routines (procedures and functions) for the dumped
>   databases in the output. Use of this option requires the SELECT
>   privilege for the mysql.proc table.
>
> The output generated by using --routines contains CREATE PROCEDURE and
>   CREATE FUNCTION statements to create the routines. However, these
>   statements do not include attributes such as the routine creation and
>   modification timestamps, so when the routines are reloaded, they are
>   created with timestamps equal to the reload time.
>
> If you require routines to be created with their original timestamp
>   attributes, do not use --routines. Instead, dump and reload the
>   contents of the mysql.proc table directly, using a MySQL account that
>   has appropriate privileges for the mysql database.

```
--single-transaction
```

> This option sets the transaction isolation mode to REPEATABLE READ and
>   sends a START TRANSACTION SQL statement to the server before dumping
>   data. It is useful only with transactional tables such as InnoDB,
>   because then it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time
>   when START TRANSACTION was issued without blocking any applications.

If you only need the data and don't need routines nor events, just skip those flags.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to do commit after a few commands, for example after 500 rows. That save memory but has the problem that in case of rollback only going back to the last commit.